# Can anyone explain me elaborately with example what are the differences between two events $A\cap B $ and $A | B $?

Tags: probability

Can anyone explain me elaborately with example what are the differences between two events $A\cap B $ and $A \mid B $ ?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: It is unfortunate that four answers were posted before anyone pointed out that there is no such thing as the event $A\mid B.$ Now my answer does that. This seems to be a confusion that many beginners get into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you are throwing a six-sided die. Define:

$A$ : You are throwing a 'high' number, i.e. you throw 4,5, or 6)

$B$ : You are throwing an even number, i.e you throw 2,4, or 6

Then:

$A \cap B$ : you throw a number that is high *and* even, i.e. you throw $4$ or $6$

So: $P(A \cap B) = \frac{2}{6} =\frac{1}{3}$

$A \mid B$ : you throw a number that is high *given* that it is even ... NOTE: you cannot say that this is the event of throwing a $4$ or $6$! Indeed, $A\mid B$ is not an event!

But, *given* that you throw an even number, we know you threw 2,4, or 6, and since two of thse three are high, we have:

$P(A\mid B)=\frac{2}{3}$

Answer (score 4):

As events (subsets of the probability space $\Omega$ of $(\Omega, \mathcal A, P)$), they *are* the same.

However, (in a bit simplified phrasing, applicable when $P(B) >0$), the probability spaces and measures are different: $(A\mid B)$ lives in $(B, \mathcal A|_B, X\mapsto P(X)/P(B))$.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as the event $A\mid B.$

When one speaks of $\Pr(A\mid B),$ that is not the probability of something called $A\mid B.$ Rather, it is the probability given $B$, of the event $A.$

On the other hand $A\cap B$ is actually an event, and $\Pr(A\cap B)$ is its probability.

Answer (score 2):

Related to the anser of Berci.

The expression $P(A|B)$ is not $P$ applied to an event $A|B$.  Instead, in the expression $P(A|B)$, we have a function "conditional $P$", a function of two arguments, applied to the events $A$ and $B$.

There is a probability measure $P(\cdot)$; we apply it to the event $A \cap B$ to get the number $P(A\cap B)$.

Given $B$ with positive probability, there is a probability measure $P(\cdot|B)$; we apply it to the event $A$ to get the number $P(A|B)$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a sample space $\Omega=\{1,2,3\}$ corresponding to the result of tossing a (fictitious) three-sided die.
As our prototypical examples of events, we will take $A = \{1,2\}$ (rolling the number one or two) and $B = \{1, 3\}$ (rolling the number one or three).

More generally, an event on $\Omega$ is any one of the following:
$$
\emptyset,\left\{ 1\right\} ,\left\{ 2\right\} ,\left\{ 3\right\} ,\left\{ 1,2\right\} ,\left\{ 1,3\right\} ,\left\{ 2,3\right\} ,\left\{ 1,2,3\right\}
$$
(if you are familiar with it, this is nothing than the powerset of $\Omega$).

When we *intersect* two events, we obtain another event corresponding to both events occurring. In our case, $A\cap B=\{1\}$ corresponds to rolling the number one.

A probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ is responsible for assigning probabilities to particular events. If our three-sided die is "fair", then $\mathbb{P}(A)=2/3$,
$\mathbb{P}(B)=2/3$, and $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=1/3$.

Technically speaking, $A\mid B$ is not an event. When we write $A\mid B$, we are alluding to definition of *conditional probability*:
$$
\mathbb{P}(A\mid B)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)}
$$
(note that the above is only well-defined if $\mathbb{P}(B) > 0$).
This should be interpreted as the probability that event $A$ occurs given that event $B$ has occurred.
In our running example,
$$
\mathbb{P}(A\mid B)=\frac{1/3}{2/3}=\frac{1}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

As Michael pointed out, $A\cap B$ is an event, while $A|B$ is not. Here we can see it visually:

[image]

Here we can see $A\cap B$ is represented as the intersection, or the purple space. This is the compound event where events $A$ and $B$ happen simultaneously.

$A | B$ is read as $A$ happens given $B$ has already happened beforehand. This is associated with [Conditional Probability](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability). We cannot represent this visually as this is not an event. We tend to look more at $P(A|B)$ ; that is, the probability of $A$ happening given $B$ has happened already.