# Solving the problem of conditional probability without using P($A | B$).

Tags: probability

I was trying to differentiate $A|B$ and $A \cap B$. I think understanding the following problem will clear my doubt.

There are two urns namely $U_1$ and $U_2$. $U_1$ contains three white balls and  five red balls while $U_2$ contains four white balls and five red balls. One Urn is chosen randomly and a white ball is drawn. What is the probability of drawing the white ball from the $U_1$?

If I name the event of choosing the urn is $A$ and drawing a white ball is $B$ , Then what will be the event $A \cap B$ and how the sample space will look like.

I want to determine P($A \cap B$)  by determining  $ \frac{n(A\cap B)}{n(S)} $. $S$ denotes the sample space. I know how to solve it by using conditional probability. I can not see the sample space. Can anyone elaborately explain me what will be the sample space $S$.  I want to solve this problem by the way Bram28 has solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2845608/can-anyone-explain-me-elaborately-with-example-what-are-the-differences-between/2845612#2845612)

Can anyone please help me to understand?

Comment: Is there an event $A\mid B$?

Comment: I do not know. Then what do you call $(A|B)$?

Comment: I don't: **you** used the notation $A\mid B$ and **you** called it an event. Could you explain what you mean by it?

Comment: If $B$ has already happened  then what is the probability of happening $A$?  answer will be  P$(A|B)$.@LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Am I not right?@LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: @cmi: We know what $P(A\mid B)$ means. (It has nothing to do with the temporal order of $A$ and $B$, by the way.) But you wrote about an "event" denoted by $A\mid B$. No such event occurs in $P(A\mid B)$.

Comment: Okay Okay. Don't call $A|B$ an event. Can you please help me now to understand the problem?@joriki

Comment: ????????????????????@joriki

Answer (score 1):

You call $A$ "the event of choosing an urn," but events need to be specific things. As you've stated it, $A=S$, meaning every event in your sample space involves picking an urn. That's just part of the problem setup.

Since you are looking for $P(A|B)$ and the problem is to find the "Probability of picking $U_1$ given that a white ball was drawn," you probably meant that $A$ is the event of picking $U_1$.

You say you want to find $P(A\cap B)$ (the probability of picking an urn and then picking a white ball) by finding $\frac{n(A\cap B)}{n(S)}$ (the number of ways you can draw a white ball divided by the size of the sample space). You appear to believe that these quantities are equal, but as a general rule,
$$P(A\cap B)\neq\frac{n(A\cap B)}{n(S)}.$$
You can only count on these being equal if each of the ways in which you could draw a white ball is equally likely to occur (for the urn problem, they're not). **Let's change the numbers to make this obvious**: if $U_1$ had one red, one white and $U_2$ had one red, 100 white, then $n(A\cap B)=1$ because there is 1 way to draw the white ball form $U_1$. The total number of possible outcomes is the number of balls, $n(S)=103$. So 
$$\frac{n(A\cap B)}{n(S)}=\frac1{103}.$$
But the probability of drawing the white ball from $U_1$ is $\frac12\times\frac12=\frac14$

You say that you know how to do the problem with conditional probability so you don't want any conditional probability solutions. I am quite certain that there is no correct solution method that does not involve conditional probability. You can get rid of conditional probabilities quickly with Bayes' rule, of course:
$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}.$$

You might want to post your solution as a comment and ask for help checking its accuracy.

edit:

joriki is correct that $(A|B)$ is not an event. In fact, without talking about probability, $(A|B)$ doesn't really have a meaning. $P(A|B)$ is the probability of the event $A$, but measured in a different way. By putting "$|B$" in there, what you mean is that your experiment has fundamentally changed. $P(A|B)$ means you want the chances of $A$ (picking $U_1$) in an experiment where, if event $B$ does *not* occur (a red ball is drawn), you ignore the result and start over.

$A\cap B$ is an event: the event that both event $A$ and event $B$ occur.

edit again:

You can't solve this problem in the same way as that example. In Bram28's example, there is a die being thrown, and there are 6 events that each have equal chances of occurring. These are $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. Bram28 constructs two more events of interest: $A=\{4,5,6\}$ and $B=\{2,4,6\}$. He then calculates
$$
P(A\cap B)
=\frac{n(A\cap B)}{n(S)}
=\frac{n(\{4,6\})}{n(\{1,2,3,4,5,6\})}
=\frac26
$$
**This shortcut is only correct because each event has the same probability of occurring**:
$$
P(A\cap B)
=
P(\{4,6\})
=
P(\{4\})+P(\{6\})
=
\frac16+\frac16
=
\frac26.
$$

In my 103 ball example, the events in the sample space do not have equal chances. **There is more than one way to write the sample space**. I choose to write members of $S$ as pairs with the number of the chosen urn first and a letter for the color of the drawn ball second. I'm going to pretend that every white ball in $U_2$ has a number which will be a subscript, like this:
$$
S=\{(1,W),(1,R),(2,W_1),(2,W_2),\dots,(2,W_{100}),(2,R)\}.
$$

I said that Bram28's calculation method won't work for this example because
$$
\frac{n(A\cap B)}{n(S)}=\frac{n(\{(1,W)\})}{103}=\frac1{103}.
$$

Comment: I did not get you. How $n(A \cap B)$ is 101 ? @Babamots

Comment: Sorry, I fixed that when I realized that you really must have meant that $A$ is the event of picking $U_1$. Refresh your page for a better answer.

Comment: My question still remains why 1/103 and 1/2 ? @Babamots

Comment: I think you could not understand where   my doubt is. Can you please check the link I have shared. I want to solve the problem in the same way Bram28 has done there.@Babamots

Comment: @cmi I edited again to explain this more directly.

Comment: I appreciate your effort. I am trying to understand your answer. Once I get it I will let you know.@Babamots

Answer (score 0):

Based on the events of interest you can consider the following sample space to describe your experiment:
$ S = \{ E_1, E_2, E_3, E_4\}$

where,

$A$: Pick Urn-1

$A^c$ :Pick Urn-2

$B$ : Pick a white ball

$B^c$: Pick Black ball

$E_1 = A\cap B, E_2 = A^c \cap B, E_3 =  A \cap B^c, E_4 =  A^c \cap B^c$

($A\cap B$ means "Pick a white ball from urn-1")

In particular, what you are trying to find is $P(E_1)$.

However, note that the elements of S have unequal weights (i.e, they are not equally likely). So, you can not use the naive definition of probability to find $P(E_1)$ (i.e., something like $\frac{n(A\cap B)}{n(S)}$ is not valid).

Answer (score -1):

We are all set I have E either ey and use the wishes everything is yes but even E everything eye text me eye roll eeryrhyfyr E we ye eye R Wrobleski I R really eyeyduduyr to E either way ye R to E run errands to run right by the kids are going to be able to get to my we ended up yet eye on right E eueudiey yes eyueeiy to be E either eye is E et you eyeyduduyr eye is ehufyiddh I just can't get over Wednesday unless E either ey eyueeiy I will say u we ye I ey ugh ye I email will E either way easier E it ends up being the kids ejdieydiue you can always be eye is better than nothing ye E everything is going out my E everything is

Comment: yea  I got you...……………….